# Imported enum is flagged as undefined class in Dart Editor

Tags: import, enums, dart

The DartEditor Dart Editor (version 1.9.0.dev_00_00 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.9.0-dev.0.0) doesn't seem to handle importing enums correctly.  If I have two files, 1) enum_test

```dart
library enum_test;

enum Lock {on, off}
```

and 2) test.dart

```dart
library test;

import './enum_test.dart';

bool test(Lock x) {
  switch (x) {
    case Lock.on: 
      return true;
    case Lock.off: 
      return false;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

The editor flags Lock as an undefined class in the second file.

Answer (score 2):

Enable `Enable Enums support` in menu `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Experimental` > `Enable Enums Support`.

The VM runs code with enums fine but the Analyzer requires the `--enable-enum` flag which is passed to the Analyzer by DartEditor when this preferences setting is enabled.

Comment: The Enable Enums Support was set. I have just upgraded to Dart Editor version 1.9.0.dev_01_00 (DEV) Dart SDK version 1.9.0-dev.1.0, but still have the same problem.

Comment: Any idea how to get enum working in DartPad.dev? It just says Error: Undefined name "enum", and I don't see any options to enable enums. Seems ridiculous. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing to do. Enums are stable since many years.

Comment: There is nothing to do. Enums are stable since many years.

Comment: There is nothing to do. Enums are stable since many years.